# Replace only single digit numbers with text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In column E, I want to replace only numbers 1-9 with "DELETE". However, my code replaces 1-9 in double digit numbers as well, such as 17, 28,11. How do I prevent that from happening?

```
Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart,
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="2", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="3", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="4", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="5", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="6", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="7", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="8", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="9", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

Comment: You just need to replace `LookAt:=xlPart` to `LookAt:=xlWhole`

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario, it seems much more convenient to simply use an if statement to determine everything in the range of 1-9.

A simple VBA solution to this problem might look as below. At the beginning, set the update range from E1 to the last row that contains data (in column E). Based on this range, you simply check if a particular cell has a value in the range 1-9, and if so, replace it by DELETE and otherwise keep the original value:

```
Sub ReplaceValues()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim UpdateRng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set UpdateRng = ws.Range("E1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each cell In UpdateRng
        If cell.Value >= 1 And cell.Value <= 9 Then cell.Value = "DELETE"
    Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you do not want to rely on a VBA solution, you can simply create an auxiliary column as follows and copy the following formula down as far as necessary:

```
=IF(AND(E2>=1,E2<=9),"DELETE",E2)
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error for the If-And-Then section. I know why. It is because there are #VALUE! errors in the column. Where there is no data for the column formula to work, it gives that error. I simply can't find a way to easily delete those cells.

Comment: I am busy creating a macro to easily and quickly identify speeding transgressions on a vehicle tracking report. Since the report content will be different every time, I can't use the normal filters.

Comment: @Jalize I think you have different options to achieve this. One would be to highlight the column and press `CTRL + H` and replace these values before running the macro. A second option would be to add a second if function befor the if function outlined above to your macro that replaces these values with e.g., "DELETE". The function could look as follows: `If cell.Text = "#VALUE!" Then cell.Value = "DELETE"`

Comment: Thanks so much, Karl! You were a great help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding this bit of code:

```
Cells.Replace What:="#VALUE!", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

Now it works like a charm. Thanks soooo much!